# Problem with "floatrow" package in yathesis

Tags: floatrow, yathesis

I am using `yathesis` to edit my thesis. In the main file of the template, the package "floatrow" is added automatically. I use Mac OS X 10.10.

Before today, the MacTex version is 2014. and my work is compiled successfully. Tonight, I installed the MacTeX 2015 (old version is uninstalled). Then there is a problem like follows. I do some tests and am sure the problem is the package `floatrow`. I was trying to find some resolutions on internet. Somebody suggests add package `etex` just after `\documentclass{}`, but the problem is still same. How should I do? Thank you.

Here are all the packages in the part preamble (the package of "floatrow" is treated just like the first answer):

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % À proscrire dans un vrai mémoire de thèse !
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\let\tmp\newinsert
%\let\newinsert\newbox
\usepackage{floatrow}
%\let\newinsert\tmp
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[xindy,quiet]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,safeinputenc,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy,acronyms,symbols]{glossaries}
```

And here is the log information:

```
No room for a new \count . ...finable\flrow@foot{\newinsert\flrow@foot}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{figure}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{figure}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{figure}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{figure}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{figure}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{figure}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{figure}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{figure}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{figure}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{table}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{figure}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{table}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{figure}
fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015(fixltx2e) All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
Mismatch between \language (patterns)(iflang) and setting of \languagename.
Local config file subfigure.cfg used *
No file annexes/mobileRobot.aux.
W0030(minitoc(hints)) --- The \part command is altered (minitoc(hints)) after minitoc.
W0023(minitoc(hints)) --- It may be the consequence (minitoc(hints)) of loading the ``hyperref'' package.
W0028(minitoc(hints)) --- The \chapter command is altered (minitoc(hints)) after minitoc.
W0023(minitoc(hints)) --- It may be the consequence (minitoc(hints)) of loading the ``hyperref'' package.
Overfull \hbox (17.07799pt too wide) in paragraph
Underfull \vbox (badness 4954) has occurred while \output is active []
Overfull \hbox (7.54387pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (6.87936pt too wide) in paragraph
Underfull \vbox (badness 4726) has occurred while \output is active []
/usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ./images/chap1/6-topology-hybrid.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page>] (./these.mw)<images/chap1/7-simple-topo-centre.pdf, id=1200, 304.88907pt x 142.28156pt>File: images/chap1/7-simple-topo-centre.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
/usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ./images/chap1/8-simple-topo-peer.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page> <./images/chap1/9-simple-topo-bus.pdf
/usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ./images/chap1/9-simple-topo-bus.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page> <./images/chap1/10-simple-topo-ring.pdf
/usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ./images/chap1/10-simple-topo-ring.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page>] (./these.mw)<images/chap1/11-complex-topo.pdf, id=1362, 378.66469pt x 195.73125pt>File: images/chap1/11-complex-topo.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
Overfull \hbox (6.67516pt too wide) in paragraph
Underfull \vbox (badness 2837) has occurred while \output is active []
Overfull \hbox (2.3493pt too wide) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 1189) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (1.91763pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (4.0362pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (1.69344pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (41.95688pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (12.6409pt too wide) in paragraph
W0033(minitoc(hints)) The caption package should be (minitoc(hints)) loaded BEFORE the minitoc package.
W0024(minitoc(hints)) Some hints have been written (minitoc(hints)) in the these.log file.
No file annexes/mobileRobot.aux.
There were undefined references.
Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
name{appendix.B} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
name{appendix.A} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
name{chapter*.58} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
name{chapter.6} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
name{chapter.5} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
name{chapter.4} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
name{chapter.3} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
name{chapter.2} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
name{section*.6} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
name{chapter*.5} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: why have you added the answer (without comment) into the question? that will just confuse future readers who try to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is essentially a bug in the package,

```
  \newinsert\flrow@foot
```

should have been

```
  \newbox\flrow@foot
```

I've tried to contact the author with no success so far.

See the thread starting

http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-June/037042.html

Meanwhile it is normally  OK if you load `floatrow` *first* before the classic registers run out, however here the class
makes even the start of the preamble too late, you can do

```
\documentclass{yathesis}

\let\tmp\newinsert
\let\newinsert\newbox
\usepackage{floatrow}
\let\newinsert\tmp
\begin{document}

xx

\end{document}
```

to temporarily redefine `\newinsert` while `floatrow` is loaded.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution really does work. But I need compile two times, for the first time, there are some problems with the package "varioref". Besides, after second time, the mini table of content (\minitoc) in chapter 2 shows the sections titles of chapter 1. I show all the packages in the part preamble in the question above. Could you please give some suggestions? Thank you again.

Comment: Having to compile several times for `varioref` to settle down is rather normal.

Comment: @Martial as daleif says, two or three (or more) runs is expected before tables of contents and cross references stabilise so on the face of it what you describe does not sound like a problem.

Comment: In order to be sure all the compilations (`(pdf)latex`, `biber`, `makeglossaries`, `texindy`) are run the necessary and sufficient numbers of times, you could use `latexmk` with the help of the `latexmkrc` configuration file provided with `yathesis`' samples and templates (e.g. http://tiny.cc/i7nwzx). If your main file is `thesis.tex`, just run `latexmk thesis`: you'll be sure your document is okay (except otherwise specified, with something like "Latexmk: Maximum runs of pdflatex reached without getting stable files. Did not finish processing file: 'pdflatex' needed too many passes").