# Error Floatrow package?

Tags: errors, compiling, floatrow

I have problem with floatrow package after updated package and you can see like this :

```
Command Line:   xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "msb.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\Tutorial LaTeX\05. Masalah Syarat Batas

This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(msb.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
(bodiebook.cls
Document Class: bodiebook 2014/11/16 v1.0 Tsinghua University Wd
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\bk10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\jknappen\mathrsfs.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\kpfonts\kpfonts.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3unicode-data.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-patches.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xunicode\xunicode.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmss.fd"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\unicode-math\unicode-math.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\catchfile.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fix-cm.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\unicode-math\unicode-math-xetex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\unicode-math\unicode-math-table.tex")))
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel\babel.sty"
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-bahasa\bahasai.ldf"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel\babel.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel\xebabel.def"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetexconfig\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\multicol.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titletoc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\shorttoc\shorttoc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\indentfirst.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\makecell\makecell.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\array.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\multirow\multirow.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\bm.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\subfig\subfig.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\picinpar\picinpar.sty"
Pictures in Paragraphs. Version 1.2a, July 13, 1993
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\rotating\rotating.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\longtable.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\supertabular\supertabular.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\threeparttable\threeparttable.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\booktabs\booktabs.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\dcolumn.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tabu\tabu.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\varwidth.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-xetex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex"
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.
sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.
sty")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgffor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\math\pgfmath.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\tikz.code.tex"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikz
librarytopaths.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\floatrow\floatrow.sty"
! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.485 ...finable\flrow@foot{\newinsert\flrow@foot}

? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

I dont understand "How to solve it?" But before it, I can compile my file and I use example file from this link : [elegant book](https://github.com/ElegantLaTeX/BodieBook)

Comment: Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: Did you update just that package? If so, try updating the installation generally.

Comment: No, cfr , I tried updating the installlation generally

Comment: Are you loading both `fontenc` and `fontspec`? That is not wrong 100% of the time, but it wrong 99.9% of the time. Removing packages you don't need will probably help, by the way.

Comment: @cfr I loading fontspec :\RequirePackage{mathrsfs}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{kpfonts}
\RequirePackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{xits-math.otf}

Comment: @cfr  But, before updated package, i can compile my file

Comment: Perhaps something is using an additional TeX dimension now. Hence, you're exceeding the capacity. Given that you are fairly obviously loading a bunch of packages you don't need, the best and easiest initial step is to eliminate the ones you aren't using. You should also sort the font stuff out. Unless you know precisely why you are using `fontenc`, don't load it.

Comment: I wouldn't use that class. I've seen worse but the general standard is extremely low. It isn't good and it seems to be loading a whole bunch of stuff which the author probably thought was a good idea at some point but surely isn't necessary here. It loads one set of fonts and then proceeds to completely overwrite them with yet more. It loads 9 out of 10 tabular packages known to humankind. It also loads multiple packages for figures (although mostly not the ones it claims handle figures) which will almost certainly not get along at all nicely. Internet templates are Bad News. Don't use them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25278/discussion-between-hirwanto-and-cfr).

Comment: I don't think it is responsible for loading `fontenc` though. Unless one of the many packages it loads does that. It also loads packages twice which makes debugging harder. And I don't think the `book` class has a `fancyhdr` option. Why does it load TikZ? I assumed it used it somewhere but I can't find it...

Comment: Does loading `etex` early in your document (right after `\documentclass[<options>]{<class>}`) help?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  , I load etex, Why ?

Comment: @Hirwanto - This seems to be bug in `floatrow` (see [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.live/37052)).  Does it help if you load `floatrow` earlier?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251836/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In this case, the class itself is loading `floatrow` (as well as `etex`).

Comment: @cfr you could use the same fix though (before and after the class, or just put a local copy of floatrow.sty in the current directory and fix the `\newinsert` in that copy. or put  `\RequirePackage{floatrow}` before the documentclass.