# no room for new \count error

Tags: errors

Why am I getting this error? This is my preamble which I include in the main document. My document is **EMPTY**. This worked before, but then I had to do a system restore and reinstall miktex and texmaker. the `bibliography` program is now set to `biber` and miktex is 64 version.

```
% ================================Präambel==============================
\usepackage{etex}
% Kodierung, Sprache, Patches {{{
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Ausgabekodierung; ermoeglicht Akzente und Umlaute
                            %  sowie korrekte Silbentrennung.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Erlaub die direkte Eingabe spezieller Zeichen.
                            %  Utf8 muss die Eingabekodierung des Editors sein.
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsche Sprachanpassungen (z.B. Ueberschriften).
\usepackage{microtype}      % Optimale Randausrichtung und Skalierung.
\usepackage[
    autostyle,
    ]{csquotes}             % Korrekte Anfuehrungszeichen in der Literaturliste.
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}       % Patches fuer LaTeX2e. %not needed according to debugger
\usepackage{scrhack}        % Verhindert Warnungen mit aelteren Paketen.
% }}}

% Schriftarten {{{
\usepackage{mathptmx}       % Times. Package 'times.sty' is obsolete.
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% }}}

% Text durchstreichen mit \sout; Option 'normalem' verhindert,
% dass das Makro \emph{} umdefiniert wird.  
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

% ok-zeichen usw
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% Biblatex {{{
 \usepackage[
     style=alphabetic,
     backend=biber,
     backref=true
     ]{biblatex}             % Biblatex mit alphabetischem Style und biber.
 \bibliography{resources/Literatur}% Dateiname der bib-Datei.
% }}}

% Dokument- und Texteinstellungen {{{
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    margin=2.54cm,
    marginparwidth=2.0cm,
    footskip=1.0cm
    ]{geometry}             % Ersetzt 'a4wide'.
\clubpenalty=10000          % Keine Einzelzeile am Beginn eines Paragraphen
                            %  (Schusterjungen).
\widowpenalty=10000         % Keine Einzelzeile am Ende eines Paragraphen
\displaywidowpenalty=10000  %  (Hurenkinder).
\usepackage{floatrow}       % Zentriert alle Floats.
\usepackage{ifdraft}        % Ermoeglicht \ifoptionfinal{true}{false}
\pagestyle{plain}           % keine Kopfzeilen
% \sloppy                     % großzügige Formatierungsweise
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark.\ } % Verbessert Layout mehrzeiliger Fußnoten

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \hypersetup{%
        pdftitle = {\@title},
        pdfauthor  = \@author,
    }
}
\makeatother
% }}}

% Weitere Pakete {{{
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Einfuegen von Graphiken.
\usepackage{tabu}           % Einfuegen von Tabellen.
\usepackage{multirow}       % Tabellenzeilen zusammenfassen.
\usepackage{multicol}       % Tabellenspalten zusammenfassen.
\usepackage{booktabs}       % Schönere Tabellen (\toprule\midrule\bottomrule).
\usepackage[nocut]{thmbox}  % Theorembox bspw. fuer Angreifermodell.
\usepackage{amsmath}        % Erweiterte Handhabung mathematischer Formeln.
\usepackage{amssymb}        % Erweiterte mathematische Symbole.
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[
    printonlyused
    ]{acronym}              % Abkuerzungsverzeichnis.
\usepackage[
    colorinlistoftodos,
    textsize=tiny,          % Notizen und TODOs - mit der todonotes.sty von
    \ifoptionfinal{disable}{}%  Benjamin Kellermann ist das Package "changebar"
    ]{todonotes}            %  bereits integriert.



\usepackage{listings}       % Spezielle Umgebung für...
    \lstset{                %  ...Quelltextformatierung.
        language=C,
        breaklines=true,
        breakatwhitespace=true,
        frame=L,
        captionpos=b,
        xleftmargin=6ex,
        tabsize=4,
        numbers=left,
        numberstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
        keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!50!black},
        commentstyle=\itshape\color{magenta!90!black},
        identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
        stringstyle=\color{orange!90!black},
        showstringspaces=false,
        }
% }}}
```

documentclass:

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    headings=small,
    parskip=half,           % Ersetzt manuelles setzten von parskip/parindent.
    bibliography=totoc,
    numbers=noenddot,       % Entfernt den letzten Punkt der Kapitelnummern.
    open=any,               % Kapitel kann auf jeder Seite beginnen.
%   final                   % Entfernt alle todonotes und den Entwurfstempel.
    ]{scrreprt}

% ================================Präambel==============================
\usepackage{resources/myPreamble}
% ==========================Dokumentinformationen=========================
\title{......}
\author{.......}
%\newcommand{\geburtsdatumundort}{(........)}
%\newcommand{\matrikelnr}{..........}
%\newcommand{\studiengang}{..........}
%\newcommand{\pfaddesarbeitsbereichs}{.......}
%\newcommand{\meineemail}{.......}
%\newcommand{\firstsupervisor}{.......}
%\newcommand{\secondsupervisor}{..........}
%\newcommand{\typeofdocument}{..........}
%
%% ===============PDF-Einstellungen inkl Dokument-Infos===================
%\usepackage{resources/myPDFConfig}
% ============================Tooltip-Script==============================
%\usepackage{resources/tooltipScript}
% ================================Dokument==============================
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Normally, this error can't occur, unless you are allocating **many** counters in a loop

Comment: There is no loop. I get this message just from using this preamble. I ahve also tried deleting every temporary file and recompiling. This is the error log:

! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
\fi
l.485 ...finable\flrow@foot{\newinsert\flrow@foot}

Comment: in a loop, or locally in a macro that is called many times.  you don't say what document class you're using, and you don't show any user-defined macros, so we're unable to replicate the error, which is necessary to be able to identify what's happening.  (but welcome to tex.sx anyway.)

Comment: Yes, comment out `\usepackage{etex}` -- normally, you shouldn't need that package with an up-to-date TeX distribution in almost any case. The culprits are `floatrow` and `etex`, but I don't know why at the moment

Comment: Thanks, removing etex helped. Others suggested putting it even before documentclass using requirepackage, but for a different problem which it seems I am not having anymore.

hyperref is in its own .sty file, with other pdf settings

Comment: @DBRN: Yes, but without adding `hyperref` your example wasn't compilable at all

Comment: @Ian: I don't know. I am just starting working on my thesis and this is a combination of 3 different templates. if you see duplicates there providing the same function, feel free to point them out.

Comment: @DBRN --- It's best to keep things as simple as possible: avoid loading packages unless you need them.

Comment: yes was looking http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251834/problem-with-floatrow-package-in-yathesis/251836#251836

Comment: why are you loading mathptm, heleve and lmodern all at the same time? Do you want your main body font to be times or latin modern, it can't be _both_ ? setting widow and clubpenalty that way will have mostly bad effects,

Comment: This example is incredibly non-minimal.  If you throw your whole house and the kitchen sink into a document, you can expect some strange side-effects, and this appears to be one of them.  Do you really *need* all those packages?  In any case, adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` and removing `\usepackage{etex}` solved the problem on my end; the process of producing a minimal example would almost certainly have revealed this to you.

Answer (score 7):

Normally in old (pre-2015) with `etex` package, not post 2015 latex releases 9when `etex` package should not normally be used) you will not get this error unless you use over 30 thousand counts, which is unlikely.

However you also get it in old latex releases if you use too many inserts (you can only have 250 of them) `floatrow` mistakenly uses `\newinsert` rather than `\newbox` in one place which doesn't affect the behaviour unless you run out of inserts.

In the 2015/10/01 latex release, `\newinsert` was changed so that you are very unlikely to run out of inserts (as there 52 boxes pre-allocated for use by floats and (now) inserts).

Thus your example runs without error in current latex releases if you delete

```
\usepackage{etex}
```

and add

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Note `hyperref` must always have been needed it could not have "worked before" as it uses hyperref features without loading the package.

Comment: This was a really cool answer. I faced a similar problem using biblatex package, but by changing \newinsert to \newbox the error vanished.

Comment: @Prelude so you have an old latex release? (also you can not change `\newinsert` to `\newbox` in general, it was a specific issue with a mistaken use in `floatrow`)

Comment: @David_Carlisle yes, I have and old version at work and this cannot be updated due to administrative restrictions. anyhow such errors for not so professional users such as me are pretty hard to find, so such answers could be really helpful.