# floatrow throws the error "No room for a new \count"

Tags: errors, packages, floatrow

I wanted captions on the side of figures, so, following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29144/30481), I tried the `floatrow` package.
This, however, resulted in the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\floatrow\floatrow.sty:485: No room for a new \count . [...finable\flrow@foot{\newinsert\flrow@foot}]
```

I figured that maybe the problem was in some conflict between packages, as using `floatrow` in a document without other packages didn't result in errors. So I tested a bit the various combinations of packages, and ended up with the following MWE reproducing the error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

This produces the error I gave above.
However, strangely enough, *removing any single package from the above list, the error disappears*.
Even better, changing the `babel` language from `italian` to `english` also removes the error!

What is happening here?

Comment: Load `floatrow` earlier than the other packages and see if that helps.

Comment: @ArashEsbati yes, that works. However I would like to understand why this happens. Also I like to keep my packages ordered so I'd prefer not having to include it before the others. My real document is of course a bit more complicated than this MWE.

Comment: See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276265/76063) and [here](https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-June/037046.html).

Comment: @ArashEsbati thanks, those are definitely relevant. I'll install the latest MiKTeX distribution ASAP (I'm currently using 2.9) and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: you should not get that error in latex 2015/10/01 but you will in 2015/01/01 it's a bug in floatrow but the new allocation system in the October release is more forgiving

Comment: it's not a bad idea to update your tex but you don't need to update the whole distribution just for this, it's just one instance of \newinsert in floatrow which is a typo for \newbox, if you fix a local copy of that it'll work fine.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right. That solved the issue. If you write is as an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll myself replicate what you written [here](https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-June/037046.html), which solves the issue

Comment: it's a duplicate of the linked question (identical issue, there are several ways to work round it) so I voted to close on that basis.