# No room for a new \count

Tags: counters

I'm compiling an absolutely massive project for the first time on a new computer (using `xelatex main.tex`). It worked fine on the last computer I built the pdf on, but on this machine, I get the error output during compilation:

```
<Things compiling fine above this point...>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatrow/floatrow.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage (No room for a new #3)
                                               \fi
1.485 ...finable\flrow@foot{\newinsert\flrow@foot}

?
```

I wish I could give you an example of some code that generates this, but this project is massive and I wouldn't even know where to begin looking. Anyway, I'm using 64-bit Arch Linux with `texlive-most` installed, and I'm using the following packages:

- tabularx
- listings
- color
- amsmath
- etex
- lsp-gb4e

Note that I've also added `\reserveinserts` directly below the import of the etex package.

EDIT: By request, the first 4 lines of main.log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.4.20) 20 APM 2016 05:41
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled
 %&-line parsing enabled
```

Comment: How current is your texsystem? (In a new latex you shouldn't need etex).

Comment: I installed it about 20 minutes ago from up-to-date pacman repos :P
I just tried etex because I found some answers that referenced it, idk what it does or anything, so if it might be a problem I can easily remove it.

Comment: Can you add the first four lines of the .log file?

Comment: since the failure is happening while the `floatrow` package is being read in (you can tell that because if it were complete, there would be a closing parenthesis matching the one preceding that line), there is something in one of the packages you're using that is gobbling up counters.  so a minimum example only needs to show your preamble, followed by `\begin{document} \end{document}`; it doesn't even need any content, although you could include "hello world" to make it look nicer.  after that's been tested, other folks here may have more questions.

Comment: @barbarabeeton sounds good, I'll give it a try in one second, need to move buildings

Comment: That didn't reproduce the error. I'm about to add the log file lines @egreg requested atm.

Comment: @ocket8888 - Have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286128/floatrow-throws-the-error-no-room-for-a-new-count), maybe it helps.

Comment: @ArashEsbati As far as I can tell, the solution to that question was to load floatrow earlier than other packages. I'm not explicitly loading floatrow, confirmed by `grep "\usepackage{floatrow}" ./* -d skip"` returning nothing when run in the project's root directory, so I don't know how I could apply that to my situation.

Comment: @ocket8888 - Some other package or the class your are using is loading `floatrow`, this is confirmed by your log file: `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatrow/floatrow.sty`.  Other solution to this issue is to update your LaTeX.  What is the result of `grep -i '^latex2e' main.log`?

Comment: The output is `LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2`

Do you mean to say that the arch repositories don't have the latest texlive builds? Why would anyone think that's a good idea?

Comment: @ocket8888 The version of LaTeX is not the latest. I guess you hit one of the obscure issues due to packages monkeying with the allocation mechanism. A minimal example showing the issue is needed.

Comment: Distros' TeX Live packages are rarely current - even Arch's. Given that TeX Live changes almost continuously except when frozen for preparation of a new release, this is pretty much inevitable, actually. If you want the latest, install upstream's and uninstall Arch's package. This is more consonant with the Arch Way than using Arch's packages, in my opinion.

Comment: well, I'll give that a shot. @egreg as I said, I have no idea what's causing this, and I don't know what would be necessary to create a minimal example.