# Template of statistics in medicine

Tags: errors, compiling, templates

I need to use the LaTeX file from statistics in medicine [template](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/10970258/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm). I do not change anything in the template, but the problem is that I cannot run to the pdf file.

How should I do to fix this?

These are the errors:

```
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsopn.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\classes\amsthm.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\algorithms\algorithm.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\algorithmicx\algorithmicx.sty"
Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style
) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\algorithmicx\algpseudocode.sty"
Document Style - pseudocode environments for use with the `algorithmicx' style
) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\listings\listings.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\listings\lstmisc.sty"
! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi
l.1219 \newcounter{lstnumber}
                             % \global
?
```

The MEW is here:

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\articletype{Article Type}%

\received{26 April 2016}
\revised{6 June 2016}
\accepted{6 June 2016}

\raggedbottom


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @CarLaTeX yes. I get the error. I give it. I my view, it should be use when we save file.

Comment: See if this post can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276265/no-room-for-new-count-error. Otherwise, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: It dies not work yet.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved it like this:

I downloaded the `.zip` file from the link you provided and unzipped that `.zip` on my desktop. Now you should be able to compile the `.tex` file without any errors.

Here are two pictures:

[image: unzip]

And the result:

[image: compilation]

Comment: I am so sad. It does not work for me. The error 

\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi
l.1219 \newcounter{lstnumber}
                             % \global

still happen.

Comment: @sagh Save your MWE in the same subdirectory where it is WileyNJD-v2.cls, then should work.