bidi error with sesamanuel class
I have this simple example with sesamanual class
\documentclass[nocrop]{sesamanuel}
%\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}

If I add bidi package this error occure (I need to avoid it showing up)
! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.149 \newinsert\@bidi@copyins@

This answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279443/54817  give solution to this error (deleting etex package which is called implicitly from sesamanuel class) but I cannot apply this solution to my case.

you can try \makeatletter \disable@package@load{etex}{}\makeatother before the class.

@UlrikeFischer my version is so much more intuitive :-)

@DavidCarlisle but mine is more modern ;-)

@UlrikeFischer I mailed  Jean-Côme Charpentier to report this.

The class loads the etex package which it should not do, you should report that to its maintainer.
If you don't want to locally fix the class you could avoid the error by forcing etex to do nothing by pushing the count allocation into the extended etex range,
\count10=400
\documentclass[nocrop]{sesamanuel}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}

Now you get no error just etex warning that it will do nothing (which is a good thing)
Package etex Warning: Extended allocation already in use.
(etex)                etex.sty code will not be used.
(etex)                To force etex package to load, add
(etex)                \RequirePackage{etex}
(etex)                at the start of the document.

